# Positioning the fixed positioned elements child elements on top of each other

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

My code is like this

```
<div class="nav-fixed">
    <div class="brand">
        Logo of the company
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Others</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="data">
    <p>
    If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed' ...
    </p>    
</div>

<div class="overlay">

</div>

 <div class="highlight">

 </div>
```

In this I have a 3 fixed position elements, the nav-bar, overlay and the highlight section..
now I want to bring the brand inside the nav-bar on top of the highlight.. then next highlight
then next overlay and then the body or nav-bar..

the css

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.highlight {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #efefef;
    z-index: 1100;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

.nav-fixed {
    background: #333;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.brand {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1200;
    position: relative;
}
.menu {
    float: right;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;

 }
```

The constraints are I cant change the order of the markup.. Here is the fiddle.. Feel free to edit..

http://jsfiddle.net/bjcth/

Comment: It is pretty much necessary to change the order of the markup if you want to rearrange the elements in such way.

Comment: lol it does look like schoolwork. Know why, coz code's too tidy :D

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Now the navigation bar is on the menu wrapper.

```
.brand {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 50px;
 line-height: 100px;
 float:left;
```